# T-SQL: August is the beginning of next years financial year, code to dynamically to change the batch ids

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, substring, case

I have a column called `batch_id` with a list of dates - 2016080184 ie date 2016 08 01 84(84, I believe a time part).

I need to update the `batch_id` (`varchar(25)`) to change to `2017010184`, based on another column `voucher_date` (`datetime`) = `2016-08-01 00:00:00.000`

So if the `voucher date` was 2016-08-02 00:00:00.000, then the `batch_id` needs to change from `2016080278` to `2017010278` (78 at the end here doesn't matter)

August is the first month for the financial year, so August would effectively become January, September would become February etc.. and the year from Aug needs to indicate the following year ie this year is 2016 therefore `batch_id` should start with 2017.

Next August `batch_id` should indicate 2018 etc..

The file I receive is always a day behind to make things more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused about your requirement for the year to change, but this should give you all you need to get started:

```
declare @BatchID nvarchar(10) = '2016080184'
select convert(nvarchar(8),dateadd(month,-7,cast(left(@BatchID,8) as date)),112) + right(@BatchID,2) as NewBatchID_SameYear
        ,convert(nvarchar(8),dateadd(month,5,cast(left(@BatchID,8) as date)),112) + right(@BatchID,2) as NewBatchID_NextYear
```

You can apply the above date changes with a `CASE` statement on the `voucher_date` column as required.

Comment: Tank you iamdave i'll give it a go with the case statement

Comment: Sorry to be a daft person, but i am new to this and programming.   I am trying to do a case statement but its fixed. Is there a way to dynamically set the date period?                                           select  @Kx_Fin_batch_ref = 
  Case when voucher_date >= '2016-08-01' and voucher_date <='2016-08-31' then 'KX-'+convert(nvarchar(8),dateadd(month,5,cast(left([batch_id],8) as date)),112) + right([batch_id],2) 
    when voucher_date >= '2016-09-01' and voucher_date <='2016-09-30' then 'KX-'+convert(nvarchar(8),dateadd(month,5,cast(left([batch_id],8) as date)),112) + right([batch_id],2)

Comment: Please explain the rules for the dynamic date period without using code.